# C# is there a faster way to get max diff between a date set than for loop

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, visual-studio

I have a  list of dates in descending order e.g.

```
var dates = {date1, date2, date3};
```

Task is to find the maximum number of days between the dates.

What I have done so far is:

```
var maxDays = 0;
var previousDate = dates.First();
foreach (var thisDate in dates.Skip(0)) 
{
    maxDays = Max(thisDate - previousDate,  maxDays);
    previousDate = thisDate;
}
```

This works fine until I get around 1000+ dates in a list.

Can you recommend any other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Your code would not compile, `Var` is not a valid keyword, neither is `Foreach`, C# is case sensitive.

Comment: What does `Skip(0)` do here?

Comment: Wouldn't the max number be the difference between the first date and the last date? Or is part of the requirement to only compare neighboring dates?

Comment: What is the datatype of `thisDate`? because the difference of two `DateTime` objects is a `Timespan`, not an `int`.

Comment: What doesn't work fine after you get 1000+ dates in the list?

Comment: Just calculate the difference and ask for `TotalDays`, i.e., `(greatest - smallest).TotalDays`.

Comment: You could do a check with the last date to see if a bigger gap is possible and do an early exit, but it's still going to be a linear algorithm.  There are also tree structures you could use to keep track of the current max if your set of dates change over time, but wouldn't be useful if this is a strict input/output situation.

Comment: Code is pseudo code to elaborate the intention.  Actual code is doing a lot more i.e.interpolating and finding business days etc. Also yes, I want the maximum gap between consecutive dates, not the max between any two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dates` is a `List<DateTime>`, you can just run a loop that starts with the first element and goes until the second-to-last element. Then inside the loop, you compare the current element with the next one, and if the difference is greater than your current max, reset it:

```
double maxDays = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var diff = (dates[i + 1] - dates[i]).TotalDays;
    if (diff > maxDays ) maxDays  = diff;
}
```

Here's a benchmark test that shows it takes about 10 milliseconds to process 1 million items:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var numDates = 1000000;
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    // initialize list with random dates
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < numDates; i++)
    {
        var day = rnd.Next(1, 29);
        var month = rnd.Next(1, 13);
        var year = rnd.Next(DateTime.MinValue.Year, DateTime.MaxValue.Year + 1);

        dates.Add(new DateTime(year, month, day));
    }

    // Sort the list descending
    dates = dates.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToList();

    // find the two neighbors with the greatest distance
    double maxDays = 0;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var diff = (dates[i] - dates[i + 1]).TotalDays;
        if (diff > maxDays) maxDays = diff;
    }
    sw.Stop();

    // Display results
    Console.WriteLine($"The greatest difference was {maxDays} days.");
    Console.WriteLine($"The comparison of {dates.Count} items took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Why use `TotalDays`?  The `TimeSpan` type (which you get when subtracting `DateTime`s) overloads the comparison operators.  You could just compare them directly.

Comment: Because he wants the value in days..? Not sure what you are suggesting to do differently.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

```
 HashSet<TimeSpan> counts = new HashSet<TimeSpan>();
 var previousDate = dates.First();
 foreach (var thisDate in dates.Skip(1))
 {
      counts.Add(previousDate - thisDate);
      previousDate = thisDate;
 }
 var max = counts.Max();
```

The idea is to not calculate the max for each iteration but rather collect the differences and then let the Max be a set operation.

Using a HashSet also reduces the number of [unique] differences that you will be checking.

I tested this with 200,000 dates and it took less than 300 milliseconds.

Comment: Faster than others

Comment: why even create a list of timespans.  couldn't you just replace the "max timespan" found with the new timespan if the new timespan is bigger?

Comment: The `HashSet` adds a bunch of time to the processing, but it can be useful if you want to store all the results.

Comment: You are correct @RufusL. That is an oversight in my part. I will correct.

Comment: @RufusL: The Hashtag reduces the cost for larger collections as it only stores unique values. For instance, if you have 200,000 differences, you may only get 10,000 unique values. Max(10,000) vs. Max(200,000).

Comment: I meant adding a `List<HashSet>` to store all the results, rather than a single `int` that stores the largest result, increases the processing time by a factor of about 4. On my machine, processing 1 million records takes about 10 milliseconds with my answer, and 40 milliseconds with yours. Either way the perf seems fine, just depends on whether or not you need to store all of the results.

Comment: @Juan How about 200,000 `GetHashCode` calls + 200,000 `Equals` calls (not counting array realocations and rehashing) + 10,000 comparison calls vs 200,000 comparison calls